# Javascript (Vuejs) object literal, looping

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object-literal

I have an object in vuejs

```
 data: {
    food: {
              monday: {
              pizza:1,
              chips:2,
              pie:0,      
          },
             tuesday: {
              pizza:1,
              chips:2,
              pie:1,       
              }
           }
}
```

I can access the value specifically with

**this.food.monday.pizza**

but how do I count the number of items eaten on monday (3 total)?

Answer (score 4):

In [ES6](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/) you can do it as follows.

```
const objectValueSum = (obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj)
        .map(food => obj[food])
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

const sum = objectValueSum(this.data.food.monday);
```

- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns the object keys
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array of the amounts
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) sums up all the amounts

Don't forget to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) for transpiling to ES5.

Comment: Objects.keys, map and reduce are functions from ES5, only the arrow notation is from ES6 in your code